# Mysql to filter by state, postcode and maternitybg (3 conditions) for Wordpress wp_usermeta table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to search by three conditions under Wordpress wp_usermeta table which is like below:

```
      umeta_id  user_id   meta_key  meta_value       
            49  3   email   schodde.virginia@saugov.sa.gov.au
        51  3   suburb  Noarlunga
        52  3   state   SA
        53  3   postcode    5168
        54  3   maternitybg Yes
        55  3   occupation  Comm midwife
        56  3   wp_user_level   0
        57  3   nick_name   Virginia
        58  3   last_name   Schodde
        59  3   first_name  Virginia
        60  3   title    
        61  3   country  
        63  3   isinstructor     
        64  3   gender   
        65  3   idf_indig_tsi    
        66  3   idf_ct_ld    
        67  3   comments     
        68  3   action   
        69  3   user_id 3
        70  3   submit  Save
        72  3   traininglocation    Adelaide
        46980   3   workplace   Noarlunga Health service
        45304   3   trainingdate    22/03/2005
        48658   3   contact_no  0883849673
        43616   3   wp_capabilities a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";s:1:"1";}
        41939   3   maternitybg Yes
```

Below is my current SQL but it's not filtering by postcode 3000:

```
    select distinct user_id from wp_usermeta where 
( meta_key='state' and meta_value= 'Vic') or 
( meta_key='postcode' and meta_value= '3000') or 
( meta_key='maternitybg' and meta_value= 'No') 
GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(meta_key) = 3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User number 3 has two rows for the `maternitybg = Yes` key, so this matches:

```
having count(meta_key) = 3
```

To fix this, add `distinct` to verify that it matches three different keys:

```
having count(distinct meta_key) = 3
```